# Apache redirecting URLs for some reason

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Why does Apache automatically redirects URLs like `http://localhost/~user/test`  to `http://localhost/~user/test.php`? How can I turn this off? I'm having problems with this and `.htaccess` because a rule like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . index.php
```

will not redirect `http://localhost/~user/test` to `index.php`, but to `test.php` instead (it considers the URL a file, I suppose).

Details:

```
httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.21 (Unix)

sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.7.3
BuildVersion:   11D50d
```

Comment: Add `options -multiviews` to the htaccess